# Can RTTI cause security issues on certain platforms?

Tags: c++, rtti

I'm being advised at my work to avoid using dynamic_cast and RTTI as it can be a performance issue and a security liability.

I understand that RTTI can have lower performance, but unsure how it can be insecure?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious what the person(s) at work that instructed you on this had to say as a response to this question.

Comment: If someone at work told you it was a security liability, why aren't you asking them to explain why instead of us?

Comment: Possibly something very specific and academical was meant, like [here](http://wenke.gtisc.gatech.edu/papers/caver.pdf). Definitely not "never-ever use dynamic_cast". As for perfomance, remember about premature optimization as well-known evil.

Comment: It is the opposite, a bad undiagnosed cast is quite exploitable.  It is the kind of thing managers would say when they know only a little bit, they'll assume that being able to see the class names back in the binary image must mean that it is easier to decompile the code.  Insecure only to the company's balance sheet.  Google "c++ rtti obfuscation" to learn more.

Comment: @MasterAler
I don't have direct communication with this higher level person, and this was something that was just mentioned during a tangential discussion that I wasn't part of (as in I'm not directly working on that project, since I'm several teams removed from them. Doing my own research and checking around no one seems to see that as a security liability, so I'm just wondering if it's just higher up only mentioned it based on some false assumption.

Comment: @HansPassant I think I agree with you here

Comment: I talked to a security engineer, and learned that there’s a way to inspect reverse engineer from RTTI breadcrumb to piece together class hierarchy. This seems to be only relevant to VS compiler. This article here explains some of it : https://blog.quarkslab.com/visual-c-rtti-inspection.html